# Marking field as External Id in managed package patch org

Tags: managed-package, externalid, patch, indexing

Can we mark a field as [External Id](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_nested_object.htm) in a [patch org](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_patches_about.htm)?

I need this so that the field will be indexed.

Comment: Question is short but clear IMHO. Added a couple of links to it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you can't as that would violate the key principle of "while ensuring that subscribers experience no visible changes to the package" that also ensures a patch org can be upgraded to the next non-patch version.

Looking in a patch org to confirm, for a custom object field I see the option disabled:

> External ID   - Set this field as the unique record identifier from an
>   external system

**So you can't.**

**PS**

In fact the restriction is broader than patch orgs: [Allow edit of ExternalId for Managed-Deployed custom fields](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BpRLAA0).

Comment: Right - you can't later decide a field should be an external id, unique etc or vice - versa - that piece is locked once the field is packaged

Comment: Thanks @Keith. Yes, the restriction is broader - we cannot mark as external id in packaging org as well.